# Jquery change status of button on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 6 Buttons, I gave each button a Default Status of false, if the user clicks on a button that corresponding Status is switching to true. Now if I Switch a button all other button Statuses shall switch to false.

Something like this worked but what is a good way to Code this for many Buttons, I do not want to repeat myself that much:

```
    toolOneStatus = false
    $('#btn-tool-one').click(function() {
        toolOneStatus = true;
        toolTwoStatus = false; ....
    }
```

Comment: Could you show your HTML and JS code. It should be possible to do this all in a couple of lines assuming you're able to have the HTML in a certain way

Comment: Also provide an explanation of what all these variables are intended to be used for

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.data()` for this. Check snippet below...

```js
$('button').click(function(){
    alert('status ' + $(this).data('status'));
    if($(this).data('status')=="false"){
        //do this
    } else {
        //do this
    }
    $(this).data('status','true')
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" data-status="false">Button1</button>
<button type="button" data-status="false">Button2</button>
<button type="button" data-status="false">Button3</button>
<button type="button" data-status="false">Button4</button>
<button type="button" data-status="false">Button5</button>
<button type="button" data-status="false">Button6</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a single `click` function and identify the button by a `data-no` attribute.

This sample adds a blue color to the active button while all others remain gray. The `activeButton` variable represents the number of the active button.

```js
var activeButton = 0;
$('.mybtns').click(function() {
    activeButton = $(this).data('no');
    console.log('active='+activeButton);
    $('.mybtns').css('background-color','rgb(221, 221, 221)');
    $(this).css('background-color','lightblue');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="mybtns" data-no="1">Test1</button>
<button class="mybtns" data-no="2">Test2</button>
<button class="mybtns" data-no="3">Test3</button>
<button class="mybtns" data-no="4">Test4</button>
<button class="mybtns" data-no="5">Test5</button>
<button class="mybtns" data-no="6">Test6</button>
<button class="mybtns" data-no="7">Test7</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

To loop through each of the buttons and execute some code for each, you can use the aptly named `.each()` function available in jquery. You can find the documentation for it here - [each()](http://api.jquery.com/each/)

Whenever a button is clicked, `.each()` executes the function for all the elements with `class=buttons` and set the `status=false`. Inside the function you can use the `$(this)` selector to select the object of the current iteration. Finally outside the loop, the button which triggered the event, is given `status=true`.

```js
$('button').click(function() {
  $(".buttons").each(function(index) {
    // Looping through each element having class "buttons"
    $(this).data("status", "false"); //Setting every button to false.
    $(this).next().html($(this).data("status"));
  });
  $(this).data("status", "true"); // Outside the loop, setting status true for the button which triggered the click event.
  $(this).next().html($(this).data("status"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="buttons" id="button1" data-status="false">Button1</button><span id="p1"></span>
<button type="button" class="buttons" id="button2" data-status="false">Button2</button><span id="p2"></span>
<button type="button" class="buttons" id="button3" data-status="false">Button3</button><span id="p3"></span>
<button type="button" class="buttons" id="button4" data-status="false">Button4</button><span id="p4"></span>
```